# C Shell Scripting - find command

Tags: scripting, csh

I am trying to use the find command, and I was wondering if there is a simpler way than regex to find files with a specific ending?

In my assignment, I have to find all files that end in .c (like a C program's source code file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't

```
find . -name '*.c'
```

simple enough?

Comment: You need to use quotes around `"*.c"` so the glob is not prematurely expanded by the shell.

Comment: Fixed.  I sometimes use `find . -name \*.c` just because it saves a keystroke.  (I wouldn't do that in a script, just interactively).